# Dynamically compose select using Linq to sql (EF6)

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to build part of query based on Expression?

```
    public List<SelectListItem> GetSelectedListFromEntity<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> property) where T : BaseEntity<int>
    {
         var result = _repository.Query<T>().Select(p => new SelectListItem()
         {
           Text = property, //? (in simple case it looks like:  p.Name + p.Category)
           Value = p.Id.ToString(),
         ).ToList();

         return result;
    }
```

For:

```
 var result = GetSelectedListFromEntity<Product>(p => p.Name + p.Category);
```

Comment: unclear what you're asking Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: mm as you wrote ..it looks the Expression<Func<T, object>> property has to return an object ..is it?

Comment: @Awesome, call the function on the item `Text = property(p).ToString()`. You basically are asking how to construct the display text for the select?

Comment: Select takes an expression so you dynamically build an expression tree representing the the expression you want and pass that in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want it to work with a db provider, something giving you an IQueryable you can do something with expression trees like this.

Given these classes:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
}

public class Product : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

Now you need a function to make the expression:

```
public Expression<Func<T, SelectListItem>> CreateExpression<T>(Expression<Func<T, string>> textExp) where T : BaseEntity
{
    var arg = textExp.Parameters.First();       
    var param = new ParameterExpression[] { arg };
    var body = Expression.MemberInit(
        Expression.New(typeof(SelectListItem)), 
        Expression.Bind(typeof(SelectListItem).GetMember("Text").First(), textExp.Body),
        Expression.Bind(typeof(SelectListItem).GetMember("Value").First(), 
            Expression.Call(
                Expression.PropertyOrField(arg, "Id"),
                "ToString",
                new Type[0]
                )));
    var exp = Expression.Lambda(body, param);
    return (Expression<Func<T, SelectListItem>>)exp;
}
```

In C# 6 it's better practice to replace those magic strings with nameof().
Then finally you can call it with something like this:

```
var items = new List<Product> { new Product { Id = 0, Name = "Test", Category = "Cat" } };

var result = items.AsQueryable().Select(CreateExpression<Product>(p => p.Name + p.Category)).ToList();
```

Now as long as you linq provider can cope with making SelectListItems you should be fine.

Comment: this is exactly what I want! Thanks.